# Перебор всех файлов в папке и запуск в каждом из них макроса

Tags: excel, vba, visual-basic

Есть функция, которая открывает по очереди все файлы в заданной папке и запускает в каждом из них макрос UpdateFile.
Макрос делает обновление данных, сохранение и закрытие файла.
Макрос UpdateFile может быть в каждом из обрабатываемых файлов или может быть в исходном файле, откуда запускается весь процесс обновления файлов.

```
Sub Obnovlenie_Sokhranenie_failov_v_papke()
Dim s As String, fldr As String, j As Integer, f As Integer
Dim rc As Range
fldr = "d:\"
s = Dir(fldr & "*.xls*")
j = 0
f = 0
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'podschyot kolichestva failov v papke
Do While s <> ""
    s = Dir
    f = f + 1
Loop

'obrabotka failov v papke
s = Dir(fldr & "*.xls*")
Do While s <> ""
    With Workbooks.Open(fldr & s)
        'deistviia s knigoi
        'Application.Run (UpdateFile) 'вот тут проблема
        Application.Wait Time:=Now + TimeValue("0:00:10") 'задержка
        .Close (True)
    End With
    s = Dir
    j = j + 1
    Application.StatusBar = "Obrabotano: " & j & " iz " & f & " failov" & " -> " & s: DoEvents
Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    Application.StatusBar = "Obrabotano: " & j & " èç " & f & " failov"

    End Sub
```

Макрос UpdateFile:

```
Sub UpdateFile()   
        'deistviia s knigoi
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
        Application.Wait Time:=Now + TimeValue("0:00:05") 'задержка
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
        ActiveWorkbook.Close True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запуск макроса из другой книги:

```
With Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fldr & s)
    Application.Run "'" & s & "'!Module1.UpdateFile"
```

*Module1* - имя модуля, в котором записан макрос.

При этом отключать/включать обновление экрана и сообщения следует только один раз, в общей процедуре.

```
With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With
```

Сохранение и закрытие книги тоже передать наружу и в макросе останется только запуск обновлений (и правильнее не активной книги, а книги, в которой находится макрос):

```
Sub UpdateFile()
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
End Sub
```